# Python: Combine pdfs based on name

Tags: python, loops, pdf

I've written some code that creates pdfs of different graphs for every column in my dataframe. The pdfs are saved in the same folder the code is saved in. I have saved the pdfs using a combination of the column name and a description of the type of graph. I've included a sample of one type of graph. This graph is saved as "columnname_histogram.pdf"

```
############################# HISTOGRAM ###############################################

palette = sns.color_palette(palette=sns.crayon_palette(sns.colors.crayons))
new_palette = itertools.cycle(palette)         
for i in data:  # Loop over all columns 
    k =data[i].astype(float) #Changing to float
    sns.set() #defaults the background
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks") #darkens grid lines
    sns.distplot(k,color=next(new_palette))  #sets which column to use
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True) 
    fig.set_size_inches(18,12)
    ax.set_title('{} Histogram'.format(i), fontweight='bold') #sets chart title based on column
    plt.savefig('{}_hist.pdf'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')  #sets file name based on column name
```

In addition to the histogram I also have a violin plot and historical line plot with the same naming conventions.

My question is, how do I get these individual pdfs and put them into one pdf for easy viewing? I am trying to get all pdfs with the same column name into one document. Any advice or example code I could follow? I haven't had any luck trying myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a defined pattern that you can use to identify the pdfs to be merged you can use PyPDF2 to merge the files together:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os    

colnames = ["col1", "col2"] # list of column names
for colname in colnames:    
    filemerger = PdfFileMerger()
    for file in os.listdir("/yourpdfdir"):
        if file.endswith(".pdf") and file.startswith(colname):
            filemerger.append(file)
    filemerger.write(colname+"_combined.pdf")
    filemerger.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. Any advice on how to identify the pdfs I want based on the name? I have multiple types of pdfs for each column. Each pdf is named after the column name of the original dataframe

Comment: Do you have a list of column names? Or is that being generated dynamically in the code?

Comment: I have a list of column names that I created from the dataframe

Comment: I have updated the answer to include file name matching. This is not perfect by any means and can create false matches etc... so do perform your own tests before using it

Comment: Woah! You'e amazing! Thank you for the great base code. I'll update with any issues I find so others can use the code as well.